# Merging two files by matching of three columns + calculating mean for the output

Tags: python, bash, merge, multiple-columns, mean

I have a small problem when merging files based on three separate columns. First, my code and the file structure and more details regarding my question below. Here is my setup so far:

```
#making directories
subprocess.call( """ mkdir %s/junctions """%(temp_dir), shell=True)
subprocess.call( """ mkdir %s/out """%(temp_dir), shell=True)

#opening a file with paths to other files
with open(sys.argv[2],"r") as j:
    #creating the output file
    subprocess.call( """ touch %s/junctions/catjunc.txt  """%(temp_dir), shell=True)

    for line in j:
        #reformatting the input file (not important for this question)
        command = """awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $1, $2-20-1, $3+20, "JUNCBJ"NR"%s", $7, ($4 == 1)? "+":"-",$2-20-1, $3+20, "255,0,0", 2, "20,20", "0,300", $7, $8 ,$5 , $6}' %s > %s"""%(line[:-1].split(".")[0].split("/")[-1],line[:-1],temp_dir + "/junctions/junc.bed")
        subprocess.call( command, shell=True)

        # So here i basically concatenate the files. However, I also want to reduce them.
        subprocess.call( """ cat %s >> %s/junctions/catjunc.txt """%( temp_dir + "/junctions/junc.bed", temp_dir), shell=True)
```

The files:

```
chrom   start   stop    ID                                                                                              count1  count2
1       14809   14989   JUNCBJ1adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       14809   14989   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   0       59      2       1
1       14809   15815   JUNCBJ2adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       14809   15815   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   0       2       2       1
1       15018   15815   JUNCBJ4adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       15018   15815   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   0       76      2       1
1       15927   16626   JUNCBJ5adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       15927   16626   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   0       4       2       1
1       16745   16873   JUNCBJ6adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       16745   16873   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   0       2       2       1
```

All my files look like this. In column 1,2 and 3 are the chromosomes and start- and stop-coordinates. In columns 12 and 13 are some counts. In column 4 are the line IDs.
Now for my question. When concatenating both files, I want to carry over all unique lines. However, when there are two lines where all of the three first columns are identical, I want to only include one of the two in which the count values are replaced by the mean for both count columns (12 and 13). I also wanted to append both IDs (Not really important for now).

Example:

file1:

```
1       14809   14989   JUNCBJ1adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       14809   14989   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   10       59      2       1
1       14809   15815   JUNCBJ2adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       14809   15815   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   0       2       2       1
```

file2:

```
1       14809   14989   JUNCBG2adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       14809   14989   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   20       41      2       1
```

Here, the first line appears in both files with counts 10 and 59 and, 20 and 41. In the output file the line occurs once with the counts 15 and 50. The second line is simply copied.

Output:

```
                                                                                                                                                     replaced means
1       14809   14989   JUNCBJ1adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ,JUNCBG2adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       14809   14989   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   15       50      2       1
1       14809   15815   JUNCBJ2adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ    0       -       14809   15815   255,0,0 2       20,20   0,300   0       2       2       1
```

If there are any details I missed, I am happy to edit the post. Please don't judge my python-bash mix and

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk. The field separator in your files were space(s) so the values 10 and 59 were in fields 13 and 14 (`$13` and `$14` in awk). If the field separators are tabs instead add `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` before the first `{` (untested but educated guess, whose words are an invitation for demo effect) and replace all 13 with 12 and 14 with 13 (in that order ;).

```
$ awk '
{
    a13[$1,$2,$3]+=$13                # sum field 13
    a14[$1,$2,$3]+=$14                # sum field 14
    $13="XX"                          # set a replaceable key to $13
    $14="YY"                          # see above
    a0[$1,$2,$3]=$0                   # now store the record
    an[$1,$2,$3]++                    # count instances of $1,$2,$3
}
END {                                 # after all the records
    for(i in a0) {                    # loop all stored records
        sub(/XX/,a13[i]/an[i],a0[i])  # replace XXs with means
        sub(/YY/,a14[i]/an[i],a0[i])  # and YY
        print a0[i] }                 # output
}' file1 file2
1 14809 15815 JUNCBJ2adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ 0 - 14809 15815 255,0,0 2 20,20 0,300 0 2 2 1
1 14809 14989 JUNCBG2adipose_HS110_50bp_SJ 0 - 14809 14989 255,0,0 2 20,20 0,300 15 50 2 1
```

Naturally, if the keywords `XX` and `YY` appear in the data you run into problems but choose them accordingly.